# Feature Management Testing for Beta Package

Tags: beta-managed-package, lma, feature-management

We have used feature management for one of the packages. We would like to test the beta package, but we can't see the option to set Feature Management parameters in License Management Org?

When we try to open the page which uses Feature Management Parameters, it throws below error:

```
exceptionType: "System.NoDataFoundException"
isUserDefinedException: false
message: "Unable to retrieve feature parameter FeatureTest1. No results found."
```

Can someone please confirm, if it is mandatory to create a release package to test the feature management parameters?

Comment: seam like the same question as this one: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404390/how-to-test-feature-parameter-in-the-beta-package/405338#405338