# How to test Feature parameter in the beta package

Tags: apex, isv

We have beta package[package passed in the salesforce security review and released in the appexchange product] which contains Feature parameter. In LMO, beta installed orgs are not shown in the subscribers tab. Is there any other way to set value for Feature parameter? Else anyone suggest us, How to test Feature parameter in beta version package org that may helpful for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, we do not have another way to test the feature flag,
What Salesforce recommend is this:

> We recommend using this feature set in a test package and a test LMO before using it with your production package. Apply changes to your production package only after fully understanding the product’s behavior. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_best_practices.htm

In other words, they recommend creating a new LMO and a new package to test it.

What we do to test our feature flags parameters we created a workaround. The workaround consists of custom settings (protected to not allow the client to change), and on the code where we verify it, we verify the feature flag or the parameters, we only use it for testing purposes on beta versions.

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: Doesn't the protected custom setting have the same problem as the feature flag?  I.E. you can only set the custom setting by using the LMO and logging into the subscriber org that way, but beta packages aren't listed in the subscriber tab.

Comment: They are listed in the subscribe if you install it in a sandbox, but it doesn't create the license record, so you need to install the beta in the sandbox, enable parner login, login in the target org from the LMA subscriber tab